# Evaluating 10 and (10)

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

In JavaScript, what is the difference between evaluating (10) and 10?

If we put an anonymous function inside parenthesis, we can evaluate it directly like this:

```
(a => 10)() // returns 10
```

What happens when we write:

```
(10)
```

Is the parenthesis evaluated, and then the 10 evaluated, and finally the 10 returned? So with (10) we have 2 evaluations, and with 10, we have 1 evaluation?

Comment: the first is an IIFE which return 10. the second does not return something, it is a value in parenthesis.

Comment: I had to google IIFE :)

Comment: `( )` - *The grouping operator, controls the precedence of evaluation in expressions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), you will find this about the [grouping operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-grouping-operator):

> *ParenthesizedExpression : ( Expression )*
>
> 1. Return the result of evaluating *Expression*. This may be of type Reference.
>
> NOTE This algorithm does not apply [`GetValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue) to the result of evaluating *Expression*. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesized expressions.

So, all it really does is evaluating the expression inside the parenthesis. However, as explicitly noted, it does not call `GetValue` (unlike an [*AssignmentOperator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) for example).

In other words, if you are in an expression context, `expression` and `(expression)` are equivalent.

> So with (10) we have 2 evaluations and with 10, we have 1 evaluation?

Yes.

Comment: I don't think one can objectively measure the number of "evaluations".

Comment: @Bergi: well, in theory it involves one more step. Whether implementations to that is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (a => 10)()
> ```

Defines and immediately evaluates a function.

> ```
> (10)
> ```

Is a (simple) expression with some extraneous parentheses.

In practice the former is a very inefficient way to get the same result as the latter (only slightly inefficient) expression.

The difference starts to matter if the function does other things (eg. forms a closure or has local definitions – neither possible in simple expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The code `(a => 10)` defines an anonymous function. And then by adding `()` after, you evaluate that function. However, all your function does is return the value 10. An illustrative example may be to use the code `(a => a + 1)(9)`, which returns 10.

On the other hand, the code `(10)` is just code that is directly computed (it is not a function definition). You could also write `10` or `9 + 1` for the same effect.

The difference between `(a => 10)()` and `(10)` is that the first form allows you to utilize scoped variables and thus express more complicated instructions with less code.